# Is a signal summable when given a z-transform?

Tags: convergence-divergence, transformation, signal-processing, z-transform

The output of a system is given as z-transform:
$$
Y(z)=\frac{1+z^{-2}}{(1+\frac{1}{4}z^{-1})(1-\frac{1}{2}z^{-1})}
$$
I want to know if the signal in the time domain is summable, meaning that the following is true:
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|y[n]|<B<\infty
$$
Is it enough to say: Well, there is already a $Y(z)$ given, so the infinite sum for calculating a z-transform obviously converges, which means $y[n]$ is summable? I am not sure about this, because when calculationg a z-transform the z also plays a major role if the sum converges or not:
$$
Y(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}y[n]z^{-n}
$$
How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Well you could take the inverse z-transform to see what the sequence having this z-transform is and examine its behaviour directly.

Comment: Yes that's true, but is that avoidable by already drawing conclusions based on $Y(z)$?

Comment: Well, if you look at the form of Y(z), and know enough about the z-transform, you will see that the absolute summability of yi is guaranteed by the coeficients of z−1 in the denominator being less than 1. But this is equivalent to knowing what form the inverse z-transform of Y(z) will take.

Comment: I know that the denominator tells me the poles of the system, which determine the stability. I am not sure in which way they are directly related to the time signal being absolute summable. Could you explain me that?

Comment: By showing that $Y(z)=K+L/(1+z^{-1}/4)+M/(1-z^{-1}/2)$ for some real numbers $K,L,M$ and knowing the form of the inverse zT of $1/(1\pm az^{-1})$, but that is where I came in.

Comment: Ok, understod, thanks